# How to find the length of an array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array

```
var fruits = [];
fruits[5] ="apple";
fruits[85] ="pinapple";
```

How can i get the count of array as 2 in node.js

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

`console.log(fruits.length)`

Comment: @DasDas.I need to get the length of  given array

Comment: var l = fruits.length;

Comment: @Viva.its wrong .it will output as 86.But i need  the out put as 2

Comment: @LintoPD , sorry . You wanted  the number of defined items from array  , not the actual length . :)

Answer (score 3):

While

```
fruits.length
```

will give you the highest index plus 1 (86)

you can use

```
fruits.filter(function(x){return x !== 'undefined'}).length
```

to get the number of non-undefined elements in the arrya

Answer (score 3):

```
var i =0;    

fruits.forEach(function(entry){

i=i+1; 
});

console.log(i);
```